# How to align widgets to top in Column class using NavigationRai

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to put my `Text` widget at the upper left side of my `Homepage`.

[image]

[image: main.dart]

[image: home_page.dart]

Comment: Enter your code in text format and do not use images to display the code.

Comment: Please consider including code-snippet, More about asking [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In your home page you are making the Column mainAxisSize min. This means the column takes up as little room as possible. I believe it is in the row widget of your main.dart file. Rows by default have cross axis alignment set to center. Try to remove mainAxisSize in your homepage Column or add CrossAxisAlignment.start to the main.dart Row.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  child: Text(
    …
  ),
),
```